# In a shared .iml file, what should the jdkName be for an IntelliJ IDEA Plugin SDK?

Tags: intellij-idea

I work on a team where we commit our `.iml` files in version control so that everyone can use them. We have an `.iml` file for a plugin module, which includes the following:

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="IDEA IC-117.798" jdkType="IDEA JDK" />
```

however, that only works for people who are using that version (`IC-117.798`) of IntelliJ (some are on 12, some are using the ultimate edition, etc.)

Is there any sort of variable like `$INTELLIJ_SDK` that could be used for the value of `jdkName` so that the `.iml` file is valid regardless of which version of IntelliJ you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should agree about the name to be used, for example `IDEA SDK` or `PLUGINS SDK`. If all the developers will have an SDK in `Project Structure` | `SDKs` with the same name, it will work without changes on all the machines.